# jquery chechbox disable using css - what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a working piece of code:

```
"zoomend": function(node) {
   if (map.getZoom() >= 8) {
      $(".dynatree-checkbox").css("disabled", "disabled"); // line 3
   }
}
```

where `$(".dynatree-checkbox")` are checkboxes. I am trying to use css in line 3, but checkboxes are not disabled after that. What is wrong?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh `disabled` is a property, not an attribute, he should really be using `.prop()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist attr() also works fine

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it always makes me confuse. can you tell me the vital difference between these two? i guess attribute is related to markup while property is more related to objects.

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` is used as an element attribute/property and not as a CSS property.

Instead you can use:

```
$(".dynatree-checkbox").prop("disabled", true);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/eDCKA/6/

Comment: Correct is either `.prop("disabled", true)` or `.attr("disabled", "disabled")`.

Comment: There shouldn't be a confusion. See, `prop` works with the native properties of the DOM object, where `checked`, `selected` and `disabled` are the type of boolean. The same as `getElementById("obj").disabled = true".

Answer (score 0):

Hey you disbaled check box in css than why are you used jquery

as like this

```
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" disabled>  // disabled check box

<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" enabled> // enabled check box
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/MrzAS/